# Rotate around a specific point instead of 0,0,0

Tags: 3d, rotations, isometry, python

I have this function to map a 3d point to a 2d face. Right now, any of the rotations will rotate around 0,0,0. How would I do it so I can set the point they rotate around?

```
def project(point,rx=0,ry=0,rz=0):
    x,y,z = point
    x0=x
    y0=y*math.cos(rx)+z*math.sin(rx)
    z0=z*math.cos(rx)-y*math.sin(rx)
    x1=x0*math.cos(ry)-z0*math.sin(ry)
    y1=y0
    z1=z0*math.cos(ry)+x0*math.sin(ry)
    x2=x1*math.cos(rz)+y1*math.sin(rz)
    y2=y1*math.cos(rz)-x1*math.sin(rz)
    return (int(x2),int(y2))
```

Comment: Translate to the point, rotate by the translated (0,0) and translate back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate around a specific point the standard trick is make at first a translation taking P in O, then the rotation around the new origin O and finally the backward translation.

In matrix notation instead of $u’=Ru$ you need to calculate $u’=R(u-OP)+OP$, where

- u is the vector to rotate
- u’ is the rotated vector
- R is the rotation matrix
- OP is the vector from O to P (that is P-O)

Comment: But what are p and o?

Comment: P is the point around you want rotate and O is the origin.

Comment: I'm not good at producing the actual code from answers like this, could you help me out a little bit?

Comment: For a generical vector v the first translation is $v’=v - OP$, in this way P goes to the origin.

Comment: In matrix notation instead of $u’=Ru$ you need to consider u’=R(u-OP)+OP

Comment: I'm not exactly a math professor. A lot of these terms are confusing to me.

Comment: I don’t know your level in math but for linear algebra the things eork in this way. I can help further if you need but the concept is precisely thus one presented.

Comment: Is there a simple edit to the math I've posted above to allow the use of a point to rotate around, instead of 0,0. Also, my level in math is 10th grade Geometry. I would still like to learn what this edit does and why it works. I just need something to learn from.

Comment: Alright I think I've almost got it, but could you explain the rotation matrix?

Comment: The edit of your code is not completely clear, it seems a rotation around each axis (but for zero angles!) with x2 and y2 as output. Could you please specify the meaning of each term, I will take a look a soon possible. Bye.

Comment: Meanwhile take also a look here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: I am trying to make a function that will project a 3d point onto a 2d plane, but also allow the point to rotate. Right now it only rotates around 0,0,0 and I don't know how to make it rotate around a non 0,0,0 point. The only terms I care about are getting x y and z to x and y.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72478/discussion-between-gimusi-and-qwerty).